# Which preposition is used with manufacturing?

Tags: prepositions

> As the size of water tanks are found small by the customer, tanks will be manufactured **with** a bigger size.

> As the size of water tanks are found small by the customer, tanks will be manufactured **in** a bigger size.

Which preposition should I use here? My teacher say “with”is better than “in”. Or is there any difference between “in” and “with”?

Comment: "As customers have found the water tanks to be too small, tanks will be manufactured in a larger size." Your teacher is wrong.

Comment: I don't think it's particularly idiomatic to use *preposition + **a larger/bigger** size* at all in the cited context. Using the indefinite article strongly implies a pre-existing range of sizes (from which ***a*** larger one can be selected). Which works if the things being manufactured are, say, *shoes* (where there's already a predefined set of "known / established shoe sizes"). But it doesn't really work for me in the context of water tanks that were made too small. The solution is to just ***make them bigger***, not "make them in a bigger size".

Comment: They're both correct, but "...in a bigger size" is more idiomatic.

Comment: Also, I'm voting to leave open because this question asks about one specific thing, not general proofreading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of the comments are correct.

As Kate said, your teacher is flat-out wrong. "Manufactured **with** a bigger size" is not idiomatic at all. "...with more room inside them" could work, but it just makes the sentence clunkier.

And as Fumble said, "**in** a larger size" is really only used when there are set sizes to select from. If the customer has a choice of sizes then "*purchased* in a larger size" would make more sense, but the manufacturer (presumably) has full control over the manufacturing process and can choose any dimensions they like. In this case the cleanest solution is to avoid any preposition and write "...tanks will be **made bigger**."

Note that "made bigger," while probably understandable in context to mean "newly-manufactured tanks will be larger than previous ones," can also mean that the existing tanks will be somehow modified to increase their size. To avoid the ambiguity we could instead say "...new tanks will be larger" which cleans it up nicely.

---

This is also an example of a sentence made a little awkward by the passive voice, as well as the plural-singular misalignment of "tanks" and "the customer." Neither choice is incorrect, but the sentence could be improved.