# With a height of or in a height of

Tags: prepositions

> The flagpole was prodeced **in** the height/length of 10 feets.

> The flagpole was prodeced **with** the height/length of 10 feets.

Which preposition should I use in the sentence? My teacher both has the same meaning but second one is better.

Comment: You mean **produced**, and the plural of **foot** is **feet**. However, neither sentence is idiomatic. _The flagpole was ten feet tall_.

Comment: How is this not a duplicate of [your own question from yesterday](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/299483/which-preposition-is-used-with-manufacturing)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment by Kate Bunting correctly points out, the most usual way to express the height of the flagpole is to say:

> The flagpole was ten feet tall.

or if the height was changed later or there is some other reason to emphasize the height at the time of production:

> The flagpole was ten feet tall when it was produced.

To try to create a grammatically correct version of the original sentence, one might say

> The flagpole was produced with a height of ten feet.

This is grammatical, but sounds unusual and awkward to a native speaker. The use of "in" rather than "with" would make it sound even less natural, although context might change this. For example, I can imagine an advertisement saying:

> Our flagpoles are produced in a variety of heights: eight, ten, twelve, and fifteen-foot models are available.

Here "in" is used to help indicate that several different heights apply to different flagpoles. But in the original example, "in" would not be used by a fluent speaker.